# CView OnSize nType is zero

Tags: c++, view, mfc, mdi

I have a problem with MFC `CView::OnSize`. `nType` parameter comes always zero regardless of window state (maximized, restored). `nFlags` of the `CWnd` subclass are also zero. What's the trouble? Or how can I catch `CView` maximize / restore event?

Comment: That should work correctly.  You should try using Spy++ to peek at the messages that are coming to and from the CView.

Comment: This is just thinking out loud, but as the view is a child of the main frame window, maybe it's only `CMainFrame` that gets the min/max notifications.